# Trigonometric substitution integral

Tags: integration

Trying to work around this with trig substitution, but end up with messy powers on sines and cosines... It should be simple use of trigonometric properties, but I seem to be tripping somewhere.

$$\int x^5\sqrt{x^2+4}dx $$

Thanks.

Comment: try x = 2tant as a substitution. The radical will go away through a trig identity

Comment: but the $$x^5$$ keeps my powers messy after that.

Comment: show us what you get after the trig sub I suggested, don't forget to replace your dx term as well!

Comment: I get:

$$\int 2^7\frac{(sin\theta)^5}{(cos\theta)^8}d\theta$$

Comment: Very good! Now rewrite your numerator as a product of sin²t*sin²t*sint and perform another trig substitution on cost, say cost = v  What is going to happen now?

Comment: Ted, your approach works fine, but perhaps Marcelo isn't fluent with reciprocal trig functions, so my approach is to apply the pythagorean theorem twice on the sin²t terms so that the numerator becomes (1-v²)(1-v²) and the denominator a plain power of v. Then we are left with good old FOIL. Can you work it out Marcelo?

Comment: Now I have:

$$\int \frac{(1+t)^\frac{5}{2} (1-t)^\frac{5}{2}}{t^8}$$

What do you mean by foil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need a trigonometric substitution. Let $u^2=x^2+4$. Then $2u\,du=2x\,dx$, so $x\,dx=u\,du$.

Rewrite $x^5\sqrt{x^2+4}\,dx$ as $x^4\sqrt{x^2+4}\,x\,dx$, and substitute. Note that $x^2=u^2-4$, so $x^4=(u^2-4)^2$. Finishing the substitution, we get $(u^2-4)^2 u^2\,du$. Expand and integrate. No trig!

Comment: True, but that's how he started, hence my follow up on that :)

Comment: You are right to do that, and an answer based on OP's start is the one that should be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

It comes out pretty well if you put $x=2\tan\theta$. Doing it carefully, remove a $\tan\theta\sec\theta$ and everything else can be expressed as a polynomial in $\sec\theta$, hence it's easily done by substitution.

But a more "efficient" substitution is $u=\sqrt{x^2+4}$, or $u^2=x^2+4$. Then $2u\,du = 2x\,dx$ andthe integral becomes
$$\int (u^2-4)^2 u^2\,du\,.$$

Answer (score 0):

Put $x^2=t$. You will recieve $\frac{1}{2}\int t^2\sqrt{t+1}\mbox{d}t$. Now put $t+1=s$ and you will recieve $$\frac{1}{2}\int (s-1)^2\sqrt{s}\mbox{d}s.$$ That should be easy now.